# ASP.NET CORE web site deploy on Linux(Ubuntu). Cannot connect to server from external computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, nginx, server

I have a asp.net core project. It is just a single page site. Im deployed this web site as a daemon on Linux. I use Nginx proxy-server + Kestrel.

When Im try to connect by http://@MyIPadress@:5000 - everything is alright. But When Im try to connect from computer, that dont have local connection with server - I catching error **connection time-out**.

### **Ping to server:**

```
packets transmitted     9
received                0
packet loss             100 %
time                    8162 ms
```

### **Open ports:**

Command: `sudo ufw status`

```
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                                   
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Also, Ports 80 and 443 forwaded on my local IP.

### **Nginx settings**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  promzona.ddns.net;
    proxy_send_timeout 1000;
    proxy_read_timeout 1000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

### **ASP.NET CORE Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot("/home/promzona/All Works/ASP CORE Tutorial")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            })
            .Build();
}
```

### **ASP.NET CORE middleware**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NEW CONNECTION");
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });                  
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/home/promzona/All Works/ASP CORE Tutorial")
            });                            
            app.UseMiddleware<CounterMiddleware>();               
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {        
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            });
        }
```

.
   `CounterMiddleware` is my middleware, that count the number of pressing button and return number of this clicks.

### **Logs**

Nginx logs show only success connections, connections from my computer. My server logs dont show unsuccess connection too.

Command: `sudo tcpdump -i enp3s0 host (my_local_ip) and port 80`

In this case I see when I am try to connect, but when I am try to connect from another machine - **connection time-out**

Command: `sudo tcpdump -i enp3s0 dst (my_IP) and port 80`

Similar situation.

## **Question**

Why external coonnection to my server failing, and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error code the browser gives when you try to access your site? In addition: did you set port forwarding on your router?

Comment: Ubuntu has a firewall built-in just like Windows. You need to open the web server ports to make it a real web server to accept external connections.